# Assigning a function to a button - what does lambda do differently?

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I know that to call a function when a button is clicked, we write `command = name_of_function` within the button widget parentheses. But, when we try to pass a value into the function by adding an argument within parentheses after the function name, the function is called too early and not when the button is clicked.

I know that we can use `lambda` to get around this e.g. `command = Lambda: name_of_function(argument)`.

But what I don't understand is why does `lambda` work, and not a normal function call with parentheses and arguments?

For example, this works:

```
editmenu.add_command(label="1. Problem Definition", command=lambda: changeText(0))
```

but this doesn't:

```
editmenu.add_command(label="1. Problem Definition", command=changeText(0))
```

Comment: please provide sample code

Answer (score 0):

What `lambda` does is define a new anonymous function which, when it is called, will call your function - so something like:

```
  api_call(command=lambda: my_function(23))
```

is very similar to:

```
  def temp_func():
      my_function(23)

  .....
  .....
  api_call(command=temp_func)
```

The main difference is that `temp_func` is not defined and cannot be easily be reused.

Comment: not sure the edit actually added anything, but it did remove a deliberate emphasis on the word "define" - it is definition rather than invocation (calling) which is important here - and hence my emphasis.

Comment: It may be worth noting the third option, `command=partial(my_function, 23)`. Unlike `lambda`, this at least gives you something useful instead of `<lambda>` in your tracebacks, and it's less likely to mislead novices into thinking it's an eagle function call.